# Viewing Posts On My Companies Page and Commenting On Them Or Messaging The OP

Tags: php, facebook, api, sdk

I am working on an integration script which will allow our company to view all posts on the companies facebook wall from within our CRM system and then allow support staff to comment on questions asked or in the case where something can't be discussed on the public wall have the option to send that user a private message through Facebook to request details.

Is this something which is possible with the current API and if so where would I look. I have been looking through the PHP SDK on the Facebook developer site and have been Facebook::api object but am having difficulty finding information on which methods I need to call to do what I am trying to do and how I gather the information I am after.

Cheers

Comment: This is far too broad to be answered here, the API documentation has many examples of accessing page posts, and replying to them - if you have a specific question about code you can't get to work that's fine, but 'what can i do?' is a bit too broad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP SDK just provides you with methods to *access* the Graph API. To find out, what the Graph API is all about, please read [its documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).